# R - tmap: Add thick border and transform counties with NAs to diagonal stripes

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to recreate the following maps in R using tmap:

First Map:
[image: First Map]

Second Map:
[image: Second Map]

My questions are:

1. How to transform the counties with NAs from grey (which I think is the default in tmap) to diagonal stripes that is shown in the first map?
2. How to add a thick black border showing the whole NC state like in the second map?

Currently my R code is as follows:

```
tm_shape(dataframe) +

tm_polygons("variable1", id = "county", palette = "Greens", border.col = "black") +

tm_layout(panel.labels = c("ABCD"), legend.position = c("left"))
```

Note: The border.col = "black" colors each county border to black; however I would like to have a thicker border for the whole state.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Install and load the tigris package

```
    library(tigris)
```

Obtain a spatial object containing all state shapes

```
    state <- tigris::states()
```

subset the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to access the shape of NC

```
    NC <- state[state@data$NAME == "North Carolina", ]
```

Obtain a spatial object containing all counties in NC

```
    ncCounties <- counties("North Carolina", cb = TRUE)
```

Use the qtm(), tm_shape() and tm_borders() functions

```
    library(tmap)
    qtm(ncCounties, 
        fill = NULL, 
        fillCol = "GEOID",
        borders = "#515151", )+
   tm_layout(frame = FALSE)+
   tm_shape(NC)+
   tm_borders(lwd = 3, 
         col = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added it using "map + tm_polygons("NC", border.alpha = 1.0), but got a warning message saying "One tm layer has duplicated layer types, which are omitted. To draw multiple layers of the same type, use multiple layer groups (i.e. specify tm_shape prior to each of them). I did specify tm_shape(dataframe) to get my file "map" so I don't know what the message suggests.

Comment: I can't fully replicate with the dataframe object that is in your code, but perhaps my edit to my potential answer is helpful

Comment: @SusanSwitzer Hi Susan, thanks for answering this question. I know it's been a while, but I have a follow-up question regarding your example. I am trying to plot a similar map to your example. The thing is, when I plot more than one state, the borderline **between the states** has been removed. I would like to do something similar to this reference [link](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-07-22/an-interactive-map-from-edbuild-shows-how-school-district-funding-enforces-poverty-rates). Do you have any advice/suggestions regarding this?

Comment: What does your data look like? What you passing to the fill argument?